# What type of Pixel Interpolation is used by OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, pixel, interpolation

I would like to know what type of Pixel Interpolation is used by OpenGL.
Does it use one of the Standard Pixel Interpolation techniques like Nearest Neighbor, Bilinear or Bicubic?

Answer (score 7):

If you mean the various texture filtering methods, you can set nearest neighbour, as well as bi-linear (lerp) or even tri-linear (interpolating through multiple scaled textures (mipmaps), as well as the adjacent '2D' pixels).

The filtering method can be set independently for magnification as well as minification.

You can find more info [here](http://gregs-blog.com/2008/01/17/opengl-texture-filter-parameters-explained/).